# aibo Web API をpythonを使っての実行

Tags: aibo-developer

ソニーが提供しているサンプルコードを使ってgoogle Colaboratoryで実行したいのですが、「HTTP リクエストのボディに問題があります。API のパラメーターに問題がないかを確認してください。」とでます。
このエラーの意味と改善点を教えて欲しいです。

アクセストークンの取得やdeviceldの取得はできています。

サンプルコード：
https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs#%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89

Comment: エラーは（Colabではなく）[aiboのAPIによるものですね](https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs#http-status-codes)。サンプルコードではコマンドライン引数で使用する機能とパラメータを渡すようになっています。Colabで呼び出した時のコマンドを教えていただけますか？

Comment: すみません、呼び出すコマンドというものがよくわかりません。
Colabで使ったのはそのサンプルコードのみなんです。

Comment: サンプルコードを実行するときには `$ python execute_action_api.py find_object "{\"TargetType\":\"pinkball\"}"` など、引数をつけて呼び出すことになっています（サンプルコードの下に使い方が記載されています）。実行に使ったこれを教えてください、という意味です。

Comment: わかりやすく言っていただき、ありがとうございます。とりあえず、サンプルコードは$ python execute_action_api.py find_object "{\"TargetType\":\"pinkball\"}"を使っています。もしかして、コードを書く場所を別々の枠にしているからでしょうか？

Comment: Pythonコードをファイルではなく枠として書いて、別の枠から相互に呼び出すことはできません。`$ python execute_action_api.py` と書いたときに、`execute_action_api.py` がどこに存在するのか考えてみてください（答えはNOです）。この場合、Colabに別途Pythonのソースコードファイルをアップロードする必要があるでしょう。

Comment: パソコンの中にpythonをインストール入れる必要がありますか？

Comment: その必要はありません。

Comment: すみません、すごく無知なもので、ソースコードファイルのアップロードの仕方を教えてください。

Comment: https://qiita.com/GandT/items/bd80fad2b8258ed87956 こちらを参考になさってください。

Comment: このサンプルコードのファイル名が「execute_action_api.py」なのですが、それでもソースコードをアップロードする必要があるのですか？

Comment: むむ、ちょっとわからなくなってきました。私がなにか勘違いしているんだと思います。Colabの画面を見せていただけますか（左側にフォルダやファイルの構成があって、右側にコードが出ている画面）。

Comment: 右側のコードの画面はサンプルコードのまんまですよ。アクセストークンとdeviceId の取得のところ以外は変えていません！そのままです。ちなみに「$ python execute_action_api.py」を打つ位置を同じ枠に入れたところ

File "<ipython-input-21-cd227b9f8d7e>", line 54
    $ python execute_action_api.py find_object "{\"TargetType\":\"pinkball\"}"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

というエラーが出ます。